# Do I need plugins or custom node types?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, content-management-system

I'm developing a website for my online start up. I've finalized what will be needed for me in Drupal. I just have few questions.

**The Concept:**

My website brings young musicians & album reviewers to one place.   Idea is that, every reviewer can choose 2-3 albums of any musician and we'll mail him CDs of those albums for free. In return we expect them to review those albums. We also offer certain services to musicians.

My website contains the following pages:

> 1. **Register Page:** where a visitor can  register either as *a musician* or as *an album reviewer*.
> 2. **Login & Forgot password pages:**
> 3. **Add/Edit Musician's Profile Page:** After login, musician can enter his profile information (photo, little biography & albums => for
>      each album he'll enter all the album details.)
> 4. **Add/Edit Reviewer's Profile Page:** After login, reviewer can enter his profile information (some personal information along with
>      address)
> 5. **Musicians Page:** A public page which lists all the musicians and on clicking on a musicians name/photo he'll be taken to a public
>      **Musician's Profile Page**: which displays information that was previously entered by Musician in his dashboard)
> 6. **Albums Page:** A public page which lists all the albums and on clicking on a album name/photo he'll be taken to a public **Album
>      Information Page**: which displays information that was previously
>      entered by Musician in his dashboard)
> 7. **Addresses Page:** After login, reviewer can manage (add/edit/delete) addresses to which he wanted the Album to be
>      shipped.
> 8. **Submit Review Page:** A page where reviewer will submit his star rating & review for the album that he got in mail.
> 9. **Shipment approval Page:** Admin (we) after login, can approve/reject the requests made for shipment of CDs by reviewers
> 10. **Reivew approval Page:** Admin (we) after login, can approve/reject the reviews submitted by reviewers. when approved this
>       will be shown up in **Recent Reviews Page:** of Musician (in the
>       dashboard) and also in the corresponding page of that Album
> 11. *Few Static Pages like: About us, Home Page etc.*

As you can observe, most of the pages contains forms (containing UI elements like file upload, text box, select etc). Information has to be sanitized, verified and then store in a database. This stored information has to be later retrieved for display on some other page.

I'm planning to use CMS `Drupal`.

**Questions:**

1. I need to build a theme with these 10-12 page types and using `Form API`, `File API` & `Database API` right?
2. I don't need Nodes, Fields, Custom Nodes, Taxonomy, etc because those are needed only to those in which case information will be updated by drupal admin.
3. But if I build the these 10-12 page types using the drupal API, how would I make any one to go to that page? I mean, these won't be taking any info from content section of dashboard. I'm confused here. Something is wrong. I'm unable to express it properly.
4. I don't need any plugins too, I guess. Right?

**My Background:** I've developed websites back in early 2000s. I know a lot has changed since then. For past two weeks I've updated myself with HTML5, JS, CSS3, jquery and others. I've also gone through wordpress and just for past 2 days I'm going through Drupal. I liked Drupal better.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to read more into how Drupal works.

Here is what I would try:

1. Register Page: This is user module
2. Login & Forgot password pages: let Drupal handle it, user module.
3. Add/Edit Musician's Profile Page: This is a node type, maybe only editable by users with the artist role.
4. Add/Edit Reviewer's Profile Page:This is user profile.
5. Musicians Page: This is a view to the Artist nodetype.
6. Albums Page: This is a node type. Likely you will want to associate this with artist nodes through node reference.
7. Addresses Page: This is part of user ( a field or field collection in user profile )
8. Submit Review Page: This is comment for the album node type
9. Shipment approval Page: I would do it with a view maybe. This would depend on your workflow and module choice.
10. Reivew approval Page: This is the comment review function, let drupal handle it ( or find a module that you like )
11. Few Static Pages: Another nodetype, likely the basic page type.

If none of these made sense to you, read more into Drupal.

And the answer to the questions:

1. No you don't need to touch API with these requirement. Read on to find out how to do Drupal properly.
2. You most definitely would need node / fields /taxonomy and custom node type. User can create / update them too.
3. The thing that is wrong... is you need to read more into how to use Drupal
4. They are called Modules, and you will need it.

If you are determined, take the wild ride and read, read, read. Be ready to take 1-2 weeks of reading and practice.

Else, try to hire a Drupal Dev to help you get started. That could make it a lot faster. Like core functions you mentioned done within one day fast.